# copy constructor syntax & display the values of constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I am writing a program where I need to use copy constructor. Since I am novice in using copy constructor I do not know whether my declaration and using of copy constructor is valid or not?

Also here I am facing problem with the display function, the error is :: 
`error: prototype for 'int Student::display_student()' does not match any in class 'Student'`. What is this error?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
    private:
        int rollno;
        string name;
    public:
        Student(); 
        Student(int x, string str); 
        Student(Student &s); 
        void display_student();
};

Student::Student()
 {
  rollno = 0 ;
  name = "" ;
 }

 Student::Student(int x, string str)
 {
  rollno=x ;
  name=str ;
 }

Student::Student(Student &s)
{
  rollno = s.rollno ;
  name = s.name;
}

Student::display_student()
{
    cout << "Student Name ::" << name << endl << "Student Roll No. ::" << rollno << endl;
}


int main()
{
 Student A;
 Student B(09,"Jhonny");
 Student C(B);
 A.display_student();
 B.display_student();
 C.display_student();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void Student::display_student() {...}`. More on not-quite-right code in your favorite C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the return value in the definition of `Student::display_student()`. Try:

```
void Student::display_student()
{
    cout << "Student Name ::" << name << endl << "Student Roll No. ::" << rollno << endl;
}
```

Compiler assumes `int Student::display_student()` by default. The class declaration contains the prototype for `void display_student()` but you provided only the definition for function  `int display_student()`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy constructor signature uses generally const reference. In your case, you may use the default implementation:

```
Student(const Student&) = default;
```

You may also add copy assignment:

```
Student& operator=(const Student&) = default;
```

Comment: [Copy constructor can also have `X &` as a parameter](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#ctor-1). Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack: Indeed, you're right, Thanks for the info. (But there are no reasons for OP to use the non const version)